# In C, checking for existence of file with name matching a pattern

Tags: c, file-exists

I've seen a few methods for checking the existence of a file in C.  However, everything I've seen works for a specific file name.  I would like to check for any file that matches a particular pattern.  For instance, maybe the pattern is "lockfile*" and "lockfileA", "lockfile.txt", or "lockfile.abc" would register in the check.  The way I am doing this currently is to open the directory with opendir() then cycle through readdir() and try to match the pattern with name of each file returned.  It works, but I sure would like a more compact way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: that's how it's done, bob

Comment: @ammoQ Thanks for the word!

Comment: The wildcard is used by the shell file searching utilities. One way it can be done is to pass such a command to the shell with redirected output, and then analyse the file it creates. But it's a horrible way to go about it.

Comment: `popen("ls -1 lockfile*", "r")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [glob(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) (standardized by POSIX). You give it a wildcard pattern and it will search the filesystem for matches.

**Example:**

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   glob_t globbuf;
   if (0==glob(argv[1], 0, NULL, &globbuf)){
       char **a=globbuf.gl_pathv;

       puts("MATCHES");
       for(;*a;a++)
           puts(*a);
   }
   globfree(&globbuf);
}
```

Running:

```
./a.out 'lockfile*'
```

should give you your lockfiles.

Comment: Thanks for that! good to know :) but isn't it really bad efficiency wise? doesn't it check all places?

Comment: `lockfile*` will fire off a recursive root tree search. You'll have the matches ready in a couple of hours. Just kidding. Of course it won't "check all places". Try it out.

Comment: haha yes, but how does it work? how does it map the fs so it doesn't have to check all dirs?

Comment: If you have a pattern such as `lockfile*`, it'll need to iterate over the current  directory and look for maching names. glibc's implementation uses `readdir()` + `fnmatch()`.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that's how it should be done.

For each name `d_name` of the file, you can check it's length and if it has at least 8 characters, `strcmp` that 8 first characters to **lockfile**.

You can also use `<regex.h>` for that check.

As for the iteration, I believe that's he best way to go.

Comment: Thanks.  Trying to accept your answer but Stack is telling me I have to wait five minutes.  Remind me if I forget!

Comment: You should check @PSkocik's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42680722/451601).  You provided in your question a glob pattern, and he pointed you to **glob**(3).